# Mercurial log/diff for range of lines in a file

Tags: mercurial, diff, history

I'd like an extension or tool that helps me browse the history of a range of lines in a given file.  Say I want to look at the history of a particular function, currently at lines [start, end].  hg annotate gets me started:

```
AAA  772 06-Aug-02: void Graphics2DDXF::lineTo(double x, // the x coordinate
AAA  772 06-Aug-02:                            double y // the y cooordinate
AAA  772 06-Aug-02:                            )
AAA  772 06-Aug-02:     {
BBB 2034 30-Aug-04:     LOG;
BBB 6989 05-Dec-11: 
BBB 4638 31-Oct-07:     transform_->transform(&x,&y);
AAA  772 06-Aug-02: 
BBB 7011 06-Jan-12:     AGcRoot<Line> line = gcnew Line;
BBB 6989 05-Dec-11: 
BBB 6989 05-Dec-11:     Point3d startPoint(lastPenLocation_->x(), lastPenLocation_->y(), 0.0);
BBB 6989 05-Dec-11:     Point3d endPoint(x, y, 0.0);
BBB 6989 05-Dec-11:     line->StartPoint = startPoint;
BBB 6989 05-Dec-11:     line->EndPoint = endPoint;
BBB 6989 05-Dec-11: 
BBB 4638 31-Oct-07:     lastPenLocation_ = APoint2D::New(x,y,AToleranceID::None);
BBB 7011 06-Jan-12: 
BBB 7011 06-Jan-12:     setAndAddEntity(line);
AAA  772 06-Aug-02:     }
```

The last change to this method was changeset 7011.  I can examine that with 'hg diff -c7011'.

The hard part is what happened before that.  Starting with the annotate output for 7011-1:

```
% hg annotate -r7010 file.cpp
...
AAA  772 06-Aug-02: void Graphics2DDXF::lineTo(double x, // the x coordinate
AAA  772 06-Aug-02:                            double y // the y cooordinate
AAA  772 06-Aug-02:                            )
AAA  772 06-Aug-02:     {
BBB 2034 30-Aug-04:     LOG;
BBB 6989 05-Dec-11: 
BBB 4638 31-Oct-07:     transform_->transform(&x,&y);
AAA  772 06-Aug-02: 
BBB 6989 05-Dec-11:     Line^ line = gcnew Line;
AAA  772 06-Aug-02:     addEntityToModelSpace(line);
AAA  772 06-Aug-02: 
AAA  772 06-Aug-02:     ensureLayerAvailable();
BBB 6989 05-Dec-11:     line->LayerId = s_currentLayerObjectId;
BBB 6989 05-Dec-11: 
BBB 6989 05-Dec-11:     Point3d startPoint(lastPenLocation_->x(), lastPenLocation_->y(), 0.0);
BBB 6989 05-Dec-11:     Point3d endPoint(x, y, 0.0);
BBB 6989 05-Dec-11:     line->StartPoint = startPoint;
BBB 6989 05-Dec-11:     line->EndPoint = endPoint;
BBB 6989 05-Dec-11: 
BBB 6989 05-Dec-11:     line->LinetypeId = currentLinetypeId();
BBB 6989 05-Dec-11:     line->ColorIndex = dwgColor(getColor());
BBB 4638 31-Oct-07:     lastPenLocation_ = APoint2D::New(x,y,AToleranceID::None);
AAA  772 06-Aug-02:     }
```

So now I can see that the previous changeset affecting this range of lines was 6989.  And so on.

It would be great to have a visual tool that did this, but I would be happy with something that just gave me the sequence of changesets: 7011, 6989, etc.

It wouldn't be hard to filter the annotate output for the linenumber range and find the maximum changeset number.  What is hard is adjusting the range of lines to account for lines added and removed, especially when 'diff' claims that a change spanned the min or max of your range of lines.  At least that was hard with CVS diff output, I haven't tried it with hg diff's output.

If the tool/extension I'm dreaming of doesn't exist, are there at least any tools for computing the modified line numbers?

Thanks,

Comment: To analyze the history of a single file, I use TortoiseHg. I start with the annotated version of the file at a particular revision, then switch to file history and go down the DAG. Not as automated as you want, but does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It's not built for it, but you can approximate that by using `hg grep` to search for `.` which means *anything* in regexp.  That'll get you output like this:

```
ry4an@four:~/projects/unblog$ hg grep --all --user --date . config.yaml 
config.yaml:79:-:ry4an-hg:Mon Apr 23 22:45:24 2012 -0400:TAGLINE: I think in a monospaced font.
config.yaml:79:+:ry4an-hg:Mon Apr 23 22:45:24 2012 -0400:TAGLINE: A blog about software, projects, and other little things I build.
config.yaml:52:-:ry4an-hg:Sat Apr 30 11:25:08 2011 -0500:AUTHOR: Ry4an Brase
config.yaml:52:-:ry4an-hg:Sat Apr 30 11:25:08 2011 -0500:#DISQUS: rafaelmartins-en
config.yaml:52:-:ry4an-hg:Sat Apr 30 11:25:08 2011 -0500:TIMEZONE: UTC
config.yaml:52:+:ry4an-hg:Sat Apr 30 11:25:08 2011 -0500:#POSTS_PER_PAGE: 10
config.yaml:52:+:ry4an-hg:Sat Apr 30 11:25:08 2011 -0500:AUTHOR: Ry4an Brase
config.yaml:52:+:ry4an-hg:Sat Apr 30 11:25:08 2011 -0500:#DISQUS: your-disqus-id
config.yaml:52:+:ry4an-hg:Sat Apr 30 11:25:08 2011 -0500:TIMEZONE: UTC
config.yaml:0:+:ry4an-hg:Sat Jan 22 22:51:22 2011 -0600:TITLE: Ry4an's Unblog
config.yaml:0:+:ry4an-hg:Sat Jan 22 22:51:22 2011 -0600:TITLE_HTML: Ry4an's Unblog
config.yaml:0:+:ry4an-hg:Sat Jan 22 22:51:22 2011 -0600:TAGLINE: I think in a monospaced font.
config.yaml:0:+:ry4an-hg:Sat Jan 22 22:51:22 2011 -0600:AUTHOR: Ry4an Brase
config.yaml:0:+:ry4an-hg:Sat Jan 22 22:51:22 2011 -0600:#DISQUS: rafaelmartins-en
config.yaml:0:+:ry4an-hg:Sat Jan 22 22:51:22 2011 -0600:TIMEZONE: UTC
```

Where `+` means a line was added and `-` means it was removed.  The `--all` option means show all matches, not just the most recent match per line.

Comment: `hg grep` doesn't help.  I'm not looking for a change that contains a regex.  I want **any** change that occurs within a range of lines.

Comment: right, but by making that regex `.` (everything) and passing in `--all` you get all changes to all lines in every version in that file.  It's imperfect, but it's the best you're going to get.